# Documented Best Practices for Reverse Proxy Implementation

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

I'm looking for some best practices documentation for implementation of a reverse proxy.

We need to allow an internal database / web server incoming access to the outside world and are trying to determine the most efficient and secure method to accomplish this.

We already have a Red Hat 2 server running a mod proxy Apache configuration, but want to take a look at today's best practices (as this server is ancient).

I've googled quite a bit and have as of yet been unable to find anything less than extremely general advice related to commonplace security best practices.

I would greatly appreciate anything you could provide.

Thanks!
Erik

Comment: this depends on so many factors from your very special requirements and used proxy-servers (apache vs nginx vs  varnish vs haprox vs $you_name_it), but if you reach 100 points i'd make a writeup :)

Answer (score 12):

[NIST SP 800-44 *Guidelines on Securing Public Web Servers*](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-44-ver2/SP800-44v2.pdf) is a good starting point, though it's no magic bullet (and it's a few years old now).

In my experience some of the most important requirements and mitigations, in no particular order, are:

- Make sure that your proxy, back-end web (and DB) servers cannot establish direct outbound (internet) connections (including DNS and SMTP, and particularly HTTP). This means (forward) proxies/relays for required outbound access, if required.
- Make sure your logging is *useful* (§9.1 in the above), and *coherent*. You may have logs from multiple devices (router, firewall/IPS/WAF, proxy, web/app servers, DB servers). If you can't quickly, reliably and deterministically link records across each device together, *you're doing it wrong*. This means NTP, and logging any or all of: PIDs, TIDs, session-IDs, ports, headers, cookies, usernames, IP addresses and maybe more (and may mean some logs contain confidential information).
- Understand the protocols, and make deliberate, informed decisions: including cipher/TLS version choice, HTTP header sizes, URL lengths, cookies. Limits should be implemented on the reverse-proxy. If you're migrating to a tiered architecture, make sure the dev team are in the loop so that problems are caught as early as possible.
- Run vulnerability scans from the outside, or get someone to do it for you. Make sure you know your *footprint* and that the reports highlight deltas, as well as the theoretical TLS SNAFU du-jour.
- Understand the modes of failure. Sending users a bare default "HTTP 500 - the wheels came off" when you have load or stability problems is sloppy
- Monitoring, metrics and graphs: having normal and historic data is *invaluable* when investigating anomalies, and for capacity planning.
- Tuning: from TCP time-wait to listen backlog to SYN-cookies, again you need to make make deliberate, informed decisions.
- Follow basic OS hardening guidelines, consider the use of chroot/jails, host-based IDS, and other measures, where available.